# Update and replace strings that contain multiple quotes postgresql

Tags: postgresql, replace, delimiter, quotes, double-quotes

I have a dataset with a column that I want to split. I'm using pgadmin 4 and I'm new to PostgreSQL. The delimiters I have to use unfortunately contain quotes and double quotes:

```
1) ', " 
2) ", '
3) ", "
```

To make my life easier working with this data, I would like to replace all of these delimiter strings with something I can use more easily like '*delimiter*'. Then I will use something like this to parse my data

```
SELECT SPLIT_PART(descriptions, 'delimiter', 1)
FROM all_package_hist
```

I searched how to escape the quotes using additional single quotes (''), forward slash, and dollar signs with no luck. I tried running the following code but it has just removed my double quotes from the text and not replaced it with 'delimiter'

```
UPDATE all_package_hist SET descriptions = REPLACE(descriptions, $$', "$$, 'delimiter')
```

Instead it replaced `', "` with `'`,

Please help! Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why update?  Have you tried `regexp_split_to_array(column, '["'']?,["'']?')` ?  Inside the square brackets are one double-quote character followed by two single-quote characters (that is how you escape a single quote in postgresql).  The `?` characters can be removed if you always have quotes.  Also, CSV is not as straightforward as this since the quotes are supposed to guard against whitespace, quotes, or `,` characters that might appear within what is supposed to be an array element.

Comment: Can you link me to a description of how the regexp_split_to_array function works? I can't find any documentation on it. Or can you write out the code precisely so I can understand?

I wanted to replace because I am doing a lot more substring backbending and the 4 different delimiters I have would make all my queries exponentially more complex.

Comment: The docs are here:  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html  The match pattern as I wrote them accept the following as delimiters:  `','`, `","`, `',"`, `",'`, `,"`, `",`, `,'`, and `',`.  If you need only the first four, then get rid of the `?` characters.

Comment: @MikeOrganek I think I am almost there. I actually need the first four delimiters you listed     ',', ",", ',", and ",'     I tried the following but it did not work:     SELECT descriptions, regexp_split_to_array(descriptions, '[", ']?, [', ']?, [', "]'?, [', "]'?) split_desc
FROM all_package_hist

Comment: If you need just the first four, then it should be `["''],["'']`.  That is the same as the first one without the `?` characters included.  You do not need to repeat them.  The square brackets means that it will match one of any of the characters within the brackets, so the entire match expression should be `regexp_split_to_array(column, '["''],["'']')`

Comment: That worked! Thank you! I used unnest as well to separate the items into rows.

Comment: If you need rows, then you can use `regexp_split_to_table(column, '["''],["'']')`, instead.